# Error: Split large CSV file into multiple files below 1 MB size in Java with Line separator ('\n')

Tags: java, csv

Below is my code to convert the large tsv file into multiple files with in 1MB size.

It gives exception as below at the delimiter part for line separator since I need the line separator to check

```
    Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(fileName));

        CSVParser csvParser = new CSVParser(reader, CSVFormat.newFormat('\n'));
        int i = 0;
        String input = "";
        for (CSVRecord csvRecord : csvParser) {
            input += csvRecord.get(i);
            i++;
            if (input.length() > (1024L * 1024L)) {
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(input);
```

The exception is as below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The delimiter cannot be a line break
at org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat.validate(CSVFormat.java:1428)
at org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat.<init>(CSVFormat.java:700)
at org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat.newFormat(CSVFormat.java:588)
```

Please suggest how can I split with lines instead of bytes.

If there is another way to do this using line separators please suggest that as well. Thanks.

Comment: From what I have seen, `CSVParser` is intended to be used to parse a file based on some delimiter, e.g. a comma.  You can't use a newline as the delimiter.  Can you tell us more about these files?  What is the logic behind breaking the file into smaller pieces?  Do we need to worry about keeping words intact, and, if so, does a smaller file have to be _exactly_ 1MB, or could it be smaller/larger?

Comment: tsv=Tab separated values ? If so,  I think you should rather do `CSVFormat.newFormat('\t')` (note the `\t` in place of `\n`).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have large tsv file which I need to break into smaller files to pass it forward. The other end service has size restriction of accepting files below or equal to 1 MB only. Yes keeping the words intact is very important for me since the data is line separated it would be appropriate to split the records by line.

Comment: Then why not just read the text file line by line until you exceed 1MB?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Actually I need to process the content of the lines with string and then store it in multiple files with tsv extension, with CSVParser I felt the task will be more easy using it's csvRecord related methods.

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  Yeah I am thinking about changing the approach entirely, will try with java.nio package libraries to read file, but there are unicode characters in string which resemble needs to be parsed and processed so I am worried. Let's see will try anyway.